# dropbox SDK php cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates

Tags: php, oauth, ssl-certificate, dropbox

I'm trying to use the php dropbox sdk, but i got these error

```
Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'making the request failed (Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mydropbox\Dropbox\OAuth\PHP.php:126 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mydropbox\Dropbox\OAuth\PHP.php(126): OAuth->getRequestToken('https://api.dro...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mydropbox\index.php(18): Dropbox_OAuth_PHP->getRequestToken() #2 {main} Next exception 'Dropbox_Exception_RequestToken' with message 'We were unable to fetch request tokens. This likely means that your consumer key and/or secret are incorrect.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mydropbox\Dropbox\OAuth\PHP.php:132 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mydropbox\index.php(18): Dropbox_OAuth_PHP->getRequestToken() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mydropbox\Dropbox\OAuth\PHP.php on line 132
```

I did tried so many times, to use OpenSSL to generate new and follow all the instruction ,but it still giving me this errors.

Refer Source:http://help.discretelogix.com/miscellaneous/installing-self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-wamp-server.htm

Comment: self-signed certs can't be validated, since they're not signed by a recognized CA.

Comment: yup,but how to solve the problem?? I do have a ca-bundle.crt which is trusted, how do I pointed to it and use that instead of using server.crt

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie I answered my question..

Answer (score 1):

I found a github that do not use the CA certification, or maybe it's already taken care for me.

https://github.com/BenTheDesigner/Dropbox

it's working well for me.